# Returning a non-value property

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

In javascript, it is possible to define an object's property as a getter/setter rather than just a "plain" value:

```
Object.defineProperty( obj, 'complex_property', {
    get: function getter() { return this.protected; },
    set: function setter( value ) { this.protected = value; }
} );
```

Is there any way to return a non-value property of an object without first having its getter function evaluated so that this (or the like) is possible?

```
obj.property = function( name ) { return this.[ name ]; };

// Doesn't work:
// ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
obj.property( 'complex_property' ) = 5;
```

The last line effectively reads `6 = 5` - obviously an error - since `this.complex_property` is evaluated first, then returned. Combining closures with getter-setter properties is an effective way to simulate "private" properties and validate assignment values without having to use actual get/set functions: one of the nicer features of modern javascript. It'd be even nicer if there was a way to return an unevaluated getter/setter property: is there a way I've missed or is it just not possible? Are we stuck using `set( prop, value )` functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible with JavaScript functions. All JavaScript functions created by user code can only return values, not references (and this won't be possible by code within the browser too, starting from ES6).

> A *ReturnStatement* is evaluated as follows (bold my emphasis):
>
> 1. If the *Expression* is not present, return (return, undefined, empty).
> 2. Let exprRef be the result of evaluating *Expression*.
> 3. Return (return, **GetValue(*exprRef*)**, empty).

The only way to do so is either using a `set(property, value)` function or creating an actual setter.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a property. Well, a property descriptor at least. And it ain't pretty.

```
var prop = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj /* from question */, 'complex_property');
prop.set.call(obj, 5);
```

edit:

```
obj.property = function (name) { return Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, name); }
obj.property('complex_property').set.call(obj, 5);
```